# What to look for in a robotic lawnmower?

Tags: lawn, grass, tools, lawn-mower

The idea of a robotic lawn mower is appealing, but it seems that most of the robotic lawn mowers currently on sale are overpromising their delivery somewhat. Amazon reviews are in many cases a mixed bag, and it seems the effectiveness and use of such a device can only be correctly gauged when actually letting it loose on the lawn you intend to buy it for.

Nevertheless; what would be the main parameters to look for in a robotic lawn mower, and what are the major painpoints that still exist?

Comment: The first thing I'd look at is: how challenging is your lawn?  If it's not really simple, I'd wait a few more years before even looking.

Comment: A kill switch. You don't want it becoming sentient.

Comment: No wireless access so Skynet can't take it over.

Comment: Don't forget that it can be very appealing to be stolen - very expensive and easily stolen unless you have a very serious fence.

Answer (score 2):

a: safety features
B: battery life
C: safety features
...
Z: intelligence and adaptability in mowing

-- and if your yard is not fenced to keep little kids out don't even think of trying a robotic lawn mower because it is hard to believe how brilliant kids can be at doing unbelievably stupid things.